# winform is not displaying correctly when system font is set to medium

Tags: winforms

I have winform application having a parent form with tree control on the left side of it. Each click of a tree node will display perticular form as user control in the right side of the main form. I used table lay out panels inside the user controls. Display look good in small system font. But when I change the system font to medium, display does not look good. But when I maximise the screen display looks good.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds the tree control is not wide enough to handle the text. You should be able to test it in Design Mode by setting your system fonts to Medium.